# How can I make sure I read a complete message when using epoll

Tags: c, epoll

I have a few questions about `epoll`:

1. According to Linux man-page:

> Since  even  with  edge-triggered  epoll, multiple events can be
>   generated upon receipt of multiple chunks of data, the caller has the
>   option to specify the  EPOLLONESHOT  flag,  to tell  epoll  to 
>   disable the associated file descriptor after the receipt of an event
>   with epoll_wait(2).  When the EPOLLONESHOT flag is specified, it is
>   the caller's responsibility to rearm the file descriptor using
>   epoll_ctl(2) with EPOLL_CTL_MOD.

How if I don't use `EPOLLONESHOT` and I `read` until I get `EAGAIN`, will I lose data? I have ckecked the source code of `Libevent`, they don't use `EPOLLONESHOT`.

2. How to make sure we receive the whole request data? One solution is to add length in request data. Any other solution?

Comment: Try to summarize your questions in title so we don't have to open topic to know

Comment: @Badda: The title should **not** contain the question!

Comment: *Write a title that summarizes the specific problem* is what I wanted to say. Next time I'll directly quote the Help Center.

Comment: Why do you think you would lose data? Do you have any code showing the problem you are having?

Comment: Typically in data sent over there is usually sequencing.  Our systems would be robust enough to handle a few dropped packets.  We could receive packets as `1,2,3,5,6` so we would miss packet `4` but we'd be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use  `EPOLLONESHOT` and you always read until you get `EAGAIN`, there is no reason (except a bug in your code), why you should miss any incoming data. In this case it doesn't matter, if you use level-triggering or edge-triggering. So it is safest to always read until you get `EAGAIN`.

If you use `EPOLLONESHOT`, you also need to make sure, that you rearm the file descriptor. This is unnecessary complexity in most cases, so if you don't know why you need it, you don't need it.

Your second question is not directly related to `epoll`. The method you use for detecting beginning, end and completeness of your request depends on what protocols you are using. Having length somewhere in your request could be one of the options.